# Dependent Picklist In Sites app using IE9

Tags: visualforce

We have a force.com Sites application for our customer portal, on one particular Visualforce page we have a set of dependent picklists displayed using apex:inputfield.

In Chrome and Firefox this works fine, however, when using IE9 the dependent picklist doesn't populate with any values, no matter what is selected in the parent picklist.

Anyone come across this before/have a workaround. Unfortunately, stopping using IE9 is not an option...

Comment: I remember facing a similar issue. We had used the field in different outputPanel and that was causing the issue. Can you remove everything from the page except those 2 fields and see how it behaves?

Comment: Looks like thats the issue - thanks! if you change this to an answer I'll marked it as answered

Comment: I am glad that helped.

Comment: I am having this issue in chrome only, my dependent list works in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues using dependent fields inside a `<apex:outputPanel>` tag in IE9 browser. Moving the dependent field out of the `<apex:outputPanel>` should fix the issue.

As I had encountered this issue long time back, I am not sure why it was happening, probably an issue with the salesforce internal javascript file (dependent.js or something). When contacted salesforce support they were unable to provide a proper answer on this either.